# Inserting content before <p> tags in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, for-loop, foreach

Though this is Wordpress orientated, I think the basis of the PHP is more a Stackoverflow question:

I would like to add a template_part (similar to `include()`) before the first `<p>` in a post.

I can't add the template_part before `the_content()` because inside the `the_content()` is sometimes a `<figure>` then `<p>`:

```
<figure>....</figure>
// Want to insert here!
<p>.......</p>
<p>.......</p>
<p>.......</p>
<figure>....</figure>
<p>.......</p>
<p>.......</p>
```

These are the two codes I have tried using, but not sure how to make it go before the first `<p>`:

**Method one:**

```
$after = 1;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
if(substr_count($content, '<p>') > $after) {
    $contents = explode("</p>", $content); $p_count = 0;
    foreach($contents as $content){
        echo $content; if($p_count == $after){
            get_template_part('path/to/part');
        } $p_count++;
    }
}
```

**Method two:**

```
$paragraphAfter[1] = get_template_part('path/to/part');
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$count = count($content);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( array_key_exists($i, $paragraphAfter) ) {
        echo $paragraphAfter[$i];
    }
    echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
}
```

Preferably the more efficient method, either from above or your own :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty hack could be:

```
function add_the_string_filter( $content ) {
  $string_to_append = 'your string to add';
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>/',  $string_to_append . '<p>', $content , 1);

  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_the_string_filter' );
```

The last parameter of the `preg_replace` is the limit, which tells to replace only the first occurence.

Comment: So this works, but im curious why it's a "dirty hack" opposed to just regular code?

Comment: I don't know for sure, **maybe** there's a better way some WordPress guru would have done it.